# Echo $row['name'] only echos first name?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called users and inside that "name".

If I `print_r($row['name'])`, it only prints the first name in the cell. How come?

Phpmyadmin:

> [image: http://i.imgur.com/GJiCwp4.jpg]

Comment: Because that's all that's stored in `$row['name']`. Where are you setting it? What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should probably read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Oh sorry if my question wasn't explained good enough. I'll try to improve the questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, only the first result is placed inside the `$row` variable. To see all of them, you'll have to loop through the results like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Do something with $row['name'] here
}
```

Of course, the function used to get a row from a result and the `$result` variable depends on your implementation.